# the problem with the kendo theme style in the angular framework

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, kendo-ui

I use the kendo user interface for my angular project but I don't know how can change the size and use other themes for all elements.
For example, I would like to use a small button with danger color.

that possible to use it with a class name like `btn-danger` in **bootstrap**, but in kendo, I didn't find any property for customizing elements.

have any idea about that issue?

Comment: Which version of kendo do you use it?

Comment: that version I use it   "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^4.43.0",

Comment: a few days ago kendo released the new version, and also you can update your framework and use the property like size, color, look, round, etc ... just update your kendo ui

Answer (score 2):

you can use the new version of kendo Angular
this [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/button/appearance/) can help you

and you can use this

```
<button kendoButton themeColor="error">User Settings</button>
```